# Why won't jQuery UI Datepicker work after using jQuery to change the value of the input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a function that imports information into a form.
I am using jQuery to place a date into an input box.
The ID of the input box is "depart_date" and I am trying to insert the value of (let's say) 04/01/2012.

`$('input#depart_date').replaceWith('<input class="input_med hasDatepicker" type="text" id="depart_date" name="depart_date" value="04/01/2012">');`

This works just fine. However, I lose my datepicker.
I have even tried to "reinitialize" it by using

`$( "#depart_date" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0});`

I just don't understand how to get my datepicker back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not just changing the value, you're replacing the object entirely (and removing all the UI hooks [click, focus, blur events] along with it).

Try using just `$('#depart_date').val('04/01/2012');` to assign the value. Or, better yet `$('#datepart').datepicker('setDate', '04/01/2012');`

Comment: I've tried using .val() and .html(), but neither seem to work. The value gets inserted, but it's the same situation with .replaceWith(), datepicker does not come back. I was just using .replaceWith() as an alternative to .val() and .html(). I've also tried .attr("value", "04/01/2012").

It seems that any value assignment will remove these hooks. Any ideas?

Comment: @SamPellino: Try this: `$('#datepart').datepicker('setDate', '04/01/2012');`

Comment: Just re-tried `.val()`, I was doing something wrong before - It actually works!

Answer (score 0):

Why replace the `input`?  Why not simply change the value?

`$('input#depart_date').val("04/01/2012");`